# CSS \ JS - Long li text is expanded by default (overflow should be hidden)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several `li`s with some text in them. The width is limited, so the user is able to see the first 30 characters. I'm trying to achieve two things, add `...` after the first 30 characters (obviously `...` should disappear in expanded mode), and the second thing is the ability to expand the `li` to show the whole text. Right now, the text is expanded by default, can't understand why.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcfLgom9/) here.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="a">normal length text</li>
    <li id="b">this is a relatively long text</li>
    <li id="c">this is an example of a really long text</li>
    <li id="d">this is an example of an extremely long, pointless text. this is an example of an extremely long, pointless text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 250px;
}

div ul {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

ul li {
  list-style-position: inside;
  overflow: hidden;
  //text-overflow: elipsis;
}
```

JS:

```
$("li").on("click", function() {
  var titleLength = $(this).context.innerHTML.length;
  if (titleLength > 30) {
    if ($(this).height() == 18) {
    $(this).css('height', 'auto');
    var height = $(this).height();
      $(this).height(18).animate({height: height}, 200)
    } else {
      $(this).animate({
        height: 18
      }, 200)
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Its `ellipsis` not `elipsis` .. Notice the double letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not giving your `li` elements any restricted `height` by default, meaning they default to `auto`, thus encompass the entire string.

As your jQuery code sets their height to 18px when closed, simply add the following:

```css
ul li {
  height: 18px;
  ...
}
```

[Modified JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcfLgom9/1/).

---

On top of that:

1. You've spelled "ellipsis" incorrectly in your `text-overflow` property.
2. The `text-overflow` property will be ignored without specifying adding a `white-space` property with a value of `nowrap`.
3. After doing that, you'll need to remove and re-add the `white-space` property within your jQuery.

Here's [another modified JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tcfLgom9/2/) with all the above taken into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the setting is `ellipsis`, not `elipsis`, note the double `l`. Also, you're not constraining the size of the `li` elements, so the setting would have no effect. You need to set a `width` on the elements, as well as stop the elements wrapping by default.

To then achieve the expanding logic you could toggle a class on click which undoes the CSS rules required to make the `text-overflow` work. Try this:

```js
$("li").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('expand');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
div ul {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
ul li {
  list-style-position: inside;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
ul li.expand {
  white-space: normal;
  overflow: visible;
  text-overflow: clip;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li id="a">normal length text</li>
    <li id="b">this is a reletively long text</li>
    <li id="c">this is an example of a really long text</li>
    <li id="d">this is an example of an extremdsfsdfs sgdfdsfgdfg ertwerr wee www ely long, pointless text</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need `javascript` to add `...` after your **overflow li**

```
ul li {
  list-style-position: inside;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: elipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Then change the `white-space` attribute when click on li

```
$("li").on("click", function() {
  $(this).css('white-space','normal');
});
```

Try it yourself https://jsfiddle.net/tcfLgom9/3/